# Inconveniente ejecución de aplicación creada en Php con Mysql (PhpMyadmin), cuando esta tiene mas de una tabla

Tags: php, ajax

Equipo tengo el siguiente problema
Tengo una aplicación en la web que me funciona cuando los datos provienen de solo una tabla, dicha aplicación está en el siguiente enlace:
http://clasicotk.epizy.com/

Dicha aplicación permite navegarse o funciona bien cuando solo se hace consultas solo a una tabla, (Busqueda_por_artista, Busqueda_por_género, Busqueda_por_trabajo), pero cuando se tiene una búsqueda de dos tablas que están relacionadas no se ejecuta bien, lo anterior se ve cuando se pulsa el menú “Discos_y_sus_canciones”.

Para probar, cuando realizo la consulta en Mysql(phpmyadmin) por aparte es decir en la base de datos del hosting, si me sirve la consulta por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Cancion,Enlace,IdcancionV FROM discos, canciones WHERE discos.Iddisco=canciones.Iddisco and discos.Trabajo='De fiesta con el Binomio de oro' order by IdcancionV asc
```

Ahora bien el código que tengo en la aplicación es el siguiente:

Archivo Dysc.php:

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);   
  require_once("connect/conexion.php");
  $sql6="Select Distinct Trabajo From discos ORDER BY Trabajo ASC";
  $res6=$con->prepare($sql6);  
   $res6->execute();
   $result6 = $res6->get_result();
  $rows6 = $result6->num_rows;
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <center> 
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Listado de discos o trabajos con sus respectivas canciones </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Dysc.js"></script>        
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <style type="text/css">
      table{
          border:1px solid;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          padding: 10px;
          }
         th, td, tr{
            border: 1px solid; 
         }
      
      </style> 
      <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
         function cerrar() {
          ventana=window.self;
          ventana.opener=window.self;
          ventana.close(); }
        </script>
</head>
    
         <div align="right">  
         <a href="#" onClick="cerrar()">Volver a menú principal</a>
         </div>
         <div align="Center"> 
           <b><h3>BÚSQUEDA DE DISCOS O TRABAJOS MUSICÁLES CON SUS RESPECTIVAS CANCIONES  </h3></b>
         </div>
            <p> </p>
        <body bgcolor="D5DBDB">  
         Seleccione Trabajo:
         <select id="Trabajo" onchange="seleccioneTrabajo1()"> 
           
          <?php 
              while ($rows6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) {
                printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$rows6['Trabajo'],$rows6['Trabajo']); 
              }
            ?>
         </select>
         <br></br>
         <table>
             <tr bgcolor="#85C1E9">
             <!-- <thead> -->
              <th style="width: 30%">Iddisco</th>
              <th style="width: 30%">Cancion</th>
              <th style="width: 30%">Enlace</th>
            <!--  </thead>  -->
             </tr> 
             <tbody id="ans"> 
             </tbody>
         </table>
        </body> 
   </center>     
</html>
```

Archivo ShowDysc.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL); 

  
  echo $k6;   
  $link6 = mysqli_connect("Base de datos", "usuario", "contraseña");
  mysqli_select_db($link6, "epiz_31078268_clasicoTK");
  $tildes6 = $link6->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
  
$result6 = mysqli_query($link6, "SELECT Cancion,Enlace,IdcancionV FROM discos, canciones WHERE discos.Iddisco=canciones.Iddisco and discos.Trabajo='$k6' order by IdcancionV asc");

  while ($extraido6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) { 
      $IdcancionV6=$extraido6['IdcancionV'];
      $Cancion6=$extraido6['Cancion'];
      $Enlace6=$extraido6['Enlace'];
      print("<tr>");
      
        printf("<td style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>%s</td>",$IdcancionV6);   
      printf("<td style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>%s</td>",$Cancion6);    
      printf('<td><a href="%1$s" target="_blank">%1$s</a></td>',$Enlace6);
print("</tr>"); a
}
mysqli_free_result($result6);
mysqli_close($link6);

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo Javascript con Ajax:

```
function seleccioneTrabajo1(){
  var x = document.getElementById("Trabajo").value;
   
$.ajax({
   url:"ShowDysc.php",
   method: "POST",
   data:{
       id : x
   },
   success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $("#ans").html(data);

   }
})
}
```

En el siguiente video en YouTube, explico el problema que se presenta con la aplicación:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ikqRYWDtRI

Gracias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el problema en la pregunta misma. Si el enlace llega a caer, parte de la pregunta se perderá.

Comment: tienes un erro de sintaxis en `ShowDysc.php` te ecomiendo que investigues sobre buenas practicas de programacino ya que eso te va a ayudar a depurar los programas, la regla `INDISPENSABLE` es tabular el codigo de manera correcta, como decia en el archivo `ShowDysc.php` en la linea 25 tienes una `a` en codigo php lo que genera un error y ese archivo no se ha de estar ejecutando, si no es ese el problema cerciorate de compartir el codigo tal cual lo tienes

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, pero pese a que quite la letra "a " del código, este sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP? Si es así, inclúyelo en la pregunta yendo a [edit]

Comment: en tu select esto esta mal: `discos.Iddisco=canciones.Iddisco` como sabe que tabla es `discos` y cual es `canciones` si no estan declaradas las tablas...

Comment: Cordial saludo, el error era en la consulta en efecto la consulta es:

SELECT Cancion,Enlace,IdcancionV, Trabajo FROM discos, canciones WHERE discos.Iddisco=canciones.Iddisco and discos.Trabajo='$k6' order by IdcancionV asc

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 1):

En tu select esto esta mal: `discos.Iddisco=canciones.Iddisco` como sabe que tabla es discos y cual es canciones si no estan declaradas las tablas...

Esto debe ser Declarado en el Query como: 
`FROM tabla1 as t1, tabla2 as t2`

Esto te permitiria acceder a comparaciones como: 
`WHERE t1.Iddisco=t2.Iddisco`